# jQuery animation speed not matching CSS3 transition speed

Tags: jquery, animation, css, transition

I have a navigation menu that has links with CSS3 transitions with a speed of .2s. When those links are hovered, their submenus are displayed with jQuery using the `fadeIn` and `fadeOut` methods also with a speed of .2s (200 milliseconds).

However, the submenus seem to be animating a tad slower than the links. Could this be an easing difference or a difference simply because they're two completely different ways of "animating" something?

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(
  function(){
    $('#nav li').has('ul').hover(
      function(){
        $(this).find('ul').stop(true, true).fadeIn(200);
      },
      function(){
        $(this).find('ul').stop(true, true).fadeOut(200);
      });
});
```

CSS:

```
#nav ul li a{
    height: 40px;
    display: block;
    padding: 0 15px;
    background-color: transparent;
    line-height: 40px;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #ccc;
    text-shadow: 0 -1px 0 #002745;
    -webkit-transition: all .2s;
    -moz-transition: all .2s;
    transition: all .2s;
}
```

Is there a way to make them same speed without doing the obvious "speed up the slower animation"?

This obviously isn't anything major but if it can be fixed, it would be great.

Thanks

Comment: What's your CSS and jQuery `.animate()` code look like?

Comment: This is hard to say without your css animation code.  The best thing you could do for us is to reproduce it in jsfiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you can have an expectation that two completely different means of triggering rendering should have identical speeds. jQuery has overhead it needs to deal with whereas the CSS3 animations will use the built in rendering engine. Off the top of my head I can think of the fact that jQuery's selector engine sizzler needs to find the target, then it may need to account for browser differences, check the animation queue, etc.

Comment: Yep that's what I was thinking. I'll just have to speed up the jQuery speed a bit.

Comment: It may also help to tweak the FX interval (but this won't help with duration) - http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.fx.interval/

Answer (score 1):

Here's a comparison test of jQuery vs CSS animations: http://css3.bradshawenterprises.com/demos/speed.php

He explains that CSS animations are faster than jQuery because they are compiled algorithms in C++, rather than runtime algorithms that JavaScript requires.

A reading later rebuts show an example of  his test using JavaScript framework called [d3.js](http://mbostock.github.com/d3/) that provides comparable speeds.

Comment: Just what I was going to link to! Also, jQuery can use requestAnimationFrame now as well, so should be as fast. Perhaps I should write another comparison but using that new feature of jQuery…

Answer (score 0):

By default, jQuery's animation functions, including `fadeIn` and `fadeOut`, use an `easing` value of `swing`, which uses a roughly S-shaped acceleration curve. You might try setting `easing: 'linear'` to rule out the possibility of an easing discrepancy.